# Best way to log Exceptions and other errors to txt file in .Net Core API

Tags: .net, exception, logging, error-handling, .net-core

I'm looking for best way to logging errors and transsmision Exceptions messages to log txt file in .NET Core WEB Api application.

Comment: That's too broad a question. Without any speicifcs, one can only propose adding exception handling to your methods and use .NET Core's own logging mechanism. The default web app project template already configures logging and handling unhandled exceptions.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: *There are no standard ways to do this in NetCore*. Your only options are the Console Logger, writing your own Logging Provider or, using a third party library like Serilog or Log4Net. I dont believe MS have any plans to add a file logger into their core library because many others third party libraries already support the scenario.